# Communicating between two win2k guest Virtual boxes

Tags: java, virtualbox, corba

I have not worked much on virtual machines and I need some help in resolving the virtual machine problem. Here is my set up.

- I have two linux systems with **Virtual Box** VB1 and VB2 installed on each one.
- Created two guest windows 2000 virtual machines in each of the virtual box.
- Configured the ethernet adapter to use Bridge adapter for network connections.

I am running to run a corba server on one of the win2k guest on VB1 and running a client on one of the win2k guest on VB2. On running the client I get `connection refused exception`. This happens only when I run the server and client on two different virtual boxes.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions (http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This is better suited to http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com.

Comment: @Crowder, thanks for the advice, but this is a programming question. I just wanted to know if i am missing something while running the corba example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I myself resolved the issue. The issue was with *configuring the virtual machines*. I had to use **"Bridge Network Adapter"** as a **NIC** card in each of the vm, earlier I was using **NAT**.. so this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection refused" simply means that the client cannot open a TCP/IP connection to the server computer. That could be due to any of the following reasons:

- The client is trying to connect to a server other than the one you expect
- The server is not listening for incoming connections
- Windows firewall is blocking incoming connections from the client
- There is no TCP/IP connectivity between the machines at all (although it sounds like the DNS lookup happened correctly, otherwise you would have seen a "unknown host" error)

This is a networking issue, so to diagnose it you should try and increase the logging on your client to make sure it's connecting to the right host/port. If that doesn't help, increase the logging on the server to make sure it's listening on the correct port.

Also, if your CORBA application is using insecure IIOP then you could always turn on [ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) sniffing on your client box to see where it's connecting to.